# Copy from an auto refresh worksheet to the last row of an excel table dynamically

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel with worksheet 1 getting refreshed after every 1-2 seconds. I need to capture few columns from worksheet1 to be populated in worksheet2 after every 1 min.
Example of sheet 1 is as:

[image]

My sheet2 is as:

[image]

Please help me with the VBA code such that it will capture conversion for every currency_pair after every one minute and store it in respective table in sheet2.
Since, I am very new to VBA and i am still capturing these records manually every minute.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi jamheadart, I am still doing it manually as i am at a very basic level in VBA